# Java method taking 0 arguments and returning a double using if else statements with strings

Tags: java, if-statement, methods

I am trying to write a method which does not take any arguments and then returns a double variable. It is a postcode identifier so when a cost code is entered certain post codes need to return a double.
In my example below i need post codes that start with either "GH6 TXX" or "NC4 LXX". (X stands for any random character or digit) to return 50.0.
If any other postcode is entered then return 100.0.

However i am not getting any results back and just finding errors. I'm sure i have gone massive wrong somewhere as im not great with If Else statements within methods. Any help or knowledge on this would be great!

```
    public class multiPostcodeRange {
  //Declaring Variables
  String pcode;

  public multiPostcodeRange()
  {
     pcode = "XXX XXX";
  }

  public void multiPostcodeRange()
  {
     if (pcode("GH6 TXX", "NC4 LXX")) {
        return 100.0; }

        else {
           return 50.0;}
  }   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MultiPostcodeRange {
    private String pcode;

    public MultiPostcodeRange() {
        pcode = "XXX XXX";
    }

    public double multiPostcodeRange() {
        if (pcode.equals("GH6 TXX") || pcode.equals("NC4 LXX")) {
            return 100.0; 
        }
        else {
            return 50.0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To return double from a function you need to define a return type for the function.

```
public double multiPostcodeRange
```

Answer (score 0):

You created a class with his methods (which btw you shouldn't name as the class, but give them unique names).

Then you have to create a new instance object of that class and call the method on a main function.

For example, at the end of your code:

```
`public static void main(String args[]){
multiPostcodeRange Obj = new 
multiPostcodeRange();
Obj.meth1();
Obj.meth2();}`
```

NB remember to give those methods unique names!

Also change 2nd method body and type as AndyMan's answer